# The import java.util.Scanner conflicts with a file defined in the same file

Tags: java

```
package scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String line = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an error message saying 'The import java.util.Scanner' conflicts with a file defined in the same file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your own class is named `Scanner` and you are importing another class named `Scanner`. This means the compiler does not know which `Scanner` class you mean when you create a variable of type `Scanner`.

Try to rename your class to something else.

Alternatively you could use `java.util.Scanner` this way without renaming your own class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    ...
}
```

Comment: In my case the error underlines the import itself. How can I get rid of it and use the fully qualified name as you mention?

Answer (score 3):

You should not name your class Scanner because Scanner already exists as a class in Java.
Rename your class.

Comment: Just because a class exists with that name in the JRE, that's not necessarily a reason to avoid the name. The problem is that the original poster is trying to import a class with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your class to something else, for example :

```
package scanner;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        String line = input.nextLine();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two Scanners, rename your class to and .java file MyScanner and you're golden.